# gdalwarp for clipping images using multiple polygon in a bash shell for loop

Tags: gdalwarp, loop, command-line, for-loop, bash

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\120-140k\Hillborough_FINAL_140000_region_IGD_120570003d29ed0dc.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" D:\hillsborough_Images_work\HIL2017\mrsid.vrt D:\hillsborough_Images_work\Clipped_Images\120570003d29ed0dc.png

C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\120-140k\Hillborough_FINAL_140000_region_IGD_120570004819de834.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" D:\hillsborough_Images_work\HIL2017\mrsid.vrt D:\hillsborough_Images_work\Clipped_Images\120570004819de834.png

C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\120-140k\Hillborough_FINAL_140000_region_IGD_120570006c12a2d77.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" D:\hillsborough_Images_work\HIL2017\mrsid.vrt D:\hillsborough_Images_work\Clipped_Images\120570006c12a2d77.png

C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\120-140k\Hillborough_FINAL_140000_region_IGD_120570008cca2ea3a.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" D:\hillsborough_Images_work\HIL2017\mrsid.vrt D:\hillsborough_Images_work\Clipped_Images\120570008cca2ea3a.png
```

This worked fine but I wanted to do this task using for loop and I writed script for this but I'm doing something wrong. Can you please help me to do it correct?

```
#!/bin/sh
#    "shp" - folder for shapefiles 
#    "outputraster" - folder for output rasters
cd /home/user/cliprasters/
#  delete previous files
rm D:\hillsborough_Images_work\temp\*.png
#  run
for fname1 in D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\0-20k\*.shp do
  fname2="$(basename $fname1 .shp)"
  C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\0-20k\$fname2.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" D:\hillsborough_Images_work\HIL2017\mrsid.vrt D:\hillsborough_Images_work\temp\$fname2.png
done
```

Comment: Edit the question and fix the formatting please.

Comment: You are running `gdalwarp.exe` in the Windows `cmd` prompt but are trying to use a [Unix shell script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell). This won't work, you need to use Windows `cmd` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

try adding semicolons before do and done:

```
for fname1 in D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\0-20k*.shp;
do fname2="$(basename $fname1 .shp)" C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalwarp.exe -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline D:\hillsborough_Images_work\split_Polygon\0-20k\$fname2.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 0.500000000000000 0.500000000000000 -co "COMPRESS=LZW" D:\hillsborough_Images_work\HIL2017\mrsid.vrt D:\hillsborough_Images_work\temp\$fname2.png;
done
```

Comment: hi  thanks for your reply but still this code not working